# Short circuit evaluation VS 2017 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, short-circuiting

I'm trying to get a number from the user using std::string and want to check first if that string is empty and it contains only numbers, and then check if the number there is higher than zero

When I build it and just press enter I get an exception unhandled of invalid argument at the stoi function.

I try it in an older version of VS (2012), and get the same error.

Does short circuit evaluation works on VS?

```
static const bool is_number(const char caracter)
{
    return(caracter >= '0' && caracter <= '9');
}

template <typename T> static const bool all_numbers(const T &str)
{
    if (!str.empty())
    {
        auto it = str.cbegin();

        if ((str.front() == '+' || str.front() == '-') && (str.size()>1)) ++it;

        for (it; it != str.cend(); ++it) if (!is_number(*it))  return false;

        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str;

    do
    {
        std::cout << " Number: ";
        getline(std::cin, str);
        std::cin.clear();

    }while (!all_numbers(str) && std::stoi(str) <= 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What steps have you taken so far to solve your problem?

Comment: I could just add another do-while and it will work, but I want to know if short circuit works on VS?

Comment: What input did you provide to your program, when you encountered this outcome?

Comment: Of course short circuiting "works" on VS. It is a requirement of the language. You should have ruled that out as the explanation during your debugging.

Comment: Your logic calls `stoi` if `all_numbers` returns `false`.  Apparently this is not what you meant.

Comment: You should use more curly braces and more linebreaks to make your code more readable. And I'm not sure why you added the call to `clear()`. It seems pretty useless.

Comment: Sorry, just figure it out, I put AND instead of OR, should get some sleep, thanks btw

Comment: The major compilers (and in particular VS) have been validated by hundred thousand users during years. Such gross errors are less then impossible.

Comment: I use cin.clear() to flush the stream, It's the easiest way I find to avoid CTRL+Z errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course short-circuiting works in Visual Studio, and you could easily have verified this for yourself.

However, your logic is wrong:

```
(!all_numbers(str) && std::stoi(str) <= 0);
```

Here you're only performing `stoi` if the input *isn't* all numbers. That is clearly backwards.

I think maybe you meant to write `||` instead?